# Zipping files of specific folder in android

Tags: java, android, zip

I am trying to zip '.jpg' files stored in external storage so that I can send that .zip file to server. Here's a snippet of the code. So far, the zip folder is created but there are no files inside. And while opening the zip using winrar, i get "Unexpected end of archive" message.

```
                            String[] s = new String[10];
                            ZipManager zipManager = new ZipManager();

                            File f = new File(inputPath + _report + "/");
                            File[] files = f.listFiles();
                            for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                                File file = files[i];

                                String filePath = file.getPath();
                                if (filePath.endsWith(".jpg")) {

                                    tFilelist.add(filePath.substring(63, 98));
                                    s[a] = inputPath + _report + "/" + tFilelist.get(a);
                                    a++;
                                }
                            }

                            zipManager.zip(s, inputPath + _report + inputFile);
```

Here's ZipManager class :

```
public class ZipManager {
    private static final int BUFFER = 80000;

    public void zip(String[] _files, String zipFileName) {
        try {
            BufferedInputStream origin = null;
            FileOutputStream dest = new FileOutputStream(zipFileName);
            ZipOutputStream out = new ZipOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(
                    dest));
            byte data[] = new byte[BUFFER];

            for (int i = 0; i < _files.length; i++) {
                Log.v("Compress", "Adding: " + _files[i]);
                FileInputStream fi = new FileInputStream(_files[i]);
                origin = new BufferedInputStream(fi, BUFFER);

                ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry(_files[i].substring(_files[i].lastIndexOf("/") + 1));
                out.putNextEntry(entry);
                int count;

                while ((count = origin.read(data, 0, BUFFER)) != -1) {
                    out.write(data, 0, count);
                }
                origin.close();
            }

            out.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    private void dirChecker(String dir) {
        File f = new File(dir);
        if (!f.isDirectory()) {
            f.mkdirs();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to close your file entries. Use `out.closeEntry();` after writing the content.

```
        for (int i = 0; i < _files.length; i++) {
            Log.v("Compress", "Adding: " + _files[i]);
            FileInputStream fi = new FileInputStream(_files[i]);
            origin = new BufferedInputStream(fi, BUFFER);

            ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry(_files[i].substring(_files[i].lastIndexOf("/") + 1));
            out.putNextEntry(entry); // open your file entry
            int count;

            while ((count = origin.read(data, 0, BUFFER)) != -1) {
                out.write(data, 0, count);
            }
            out.closeEntry();  // close your file entry
            origin.close();
        }
```

Comment: could you please specify where?
FYI, I am following this tutorial as reference : https://github.com/StackTipsLab/Advance-Android-Tutorials/tree/master/AndroidZip/src/com/zipp

Comment: edited my answer, I had used a wrong identifier for your ZipOutputStream, sorry about that

Comment: Still getting the same result. The zip file's size is shown as 6.5MB , but while opening, I get the ' archive is corrupt' message. I can see only one file inside the zip with 0KB size.

Comment: OK, try `out.flush();` before calling `out.close();`

Comment: By the way, you should consider improving you exception handling, if an error occurs when reading any of your input files, you'll get resource leaks and a corrupt archive. Have a look here https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html